# How to set dynamic background image URL with linear gradient using custom CSS class in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I would like to be able to set a `background-image` using a dynamically loaded image (from my server) along with a linear gradient overlay using a custom CSS class. On page load, the CSS should look like this:

```
.container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent -30%,#121212), url(https://...)
}
```

However, the color: `#121212` needs to be set using a custom css variable called `--ion-color-dark` and the url is stored in an http response object: `this.response.imageURL`

So I would need something like this:

```
.container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent -30%,var(--ion-color-dark)), url(`${this.response.imageURL}`)
}
```

**My solution so far:**

I've figured out how to get the image url to load by doing the following in my HTML:

```
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getBackgroundImageURL()}"></div>
```

Which calls `getBackgroundImageURL()` in my component:

```
getBackgroundImageURL() {
    return `linear-gradient(transparent -30%,#121212, url(${this.response.imageURL})`;
}
```

Which is great, but I cannot figure out how to load the CSS variable to replace the hard coded `#121212` using this method. It appears I can do either one or the other, but not both.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining the variable in this way-

getBackgroundImageURL() {
    return `linear-gradient(transparent -30%,var(--my-variable-name)), url(${this.response.imageURL})`;
}

Comment: OP wants to use CSS variable. This uses member variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, so I ended up using two 'layers'. First a div which has the dynamic background image, coming from code. Then on top of that, in scss, an 'overlay', with just the linear-gradient containing your variable.

So in your case, something like:

```html
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getBackgroundImageURL()}">
  <div class="container-overlay">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```scss
.container-overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent -30%, --ion-color-dark)
}
```

You'll probably want to copy the styles you had in `container` over to `container-overlay`, especially any `padding`.